# OpenID API for Mono

Tags: mono, openid

Does anybody know of any API that offers OpenID that works on Mono? Unfortunately DotNetOpenAuth does not work on Mono, and although I have seen ServiceStack use it, I do not see a difference in how that may work with Mono while mine does not.

Any suggestions on alternative libraries, or some way to get DotNetOpenAuth to work with Mono would be highly appreciated. I am running .NET 4.5 if that helps.

[EDIT]

The error I get when trying to use DotNetOpenAuth on Mono (does not throw on Windows though) can be seen here : https://gist.github.com/Cyberlane/403bd7a3f4c794a78f6f

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: My apologies @Jester - I have updated my question with a link to what error I receive when trying to use DNOA on Mono.

Comment: what version of mono-fastcgi are you using? what version of mono are you using?

Comment: @knocte "mono --version" tells me 3.0.7, and I'm using nginx with mono-fastcgi4

Comment: how did you install mono-fastcgi4?

Comment: (I need to know the git tag of github.com/mono/xsp that you're using)

Comment: xsp is a latest from master branch (or was 2 weeks ago when I installed it). Mono is from a gz file, because I could not install from GitHub without having it already installed... I tried to update Mono (not xsp) to latest, but then I got errors about duplicate registered DLLs, so I reverted to the gz for mono, but went with XSP from GitHub. Should I be using a different branch perhaps?

Comment: @knocte are you able to get it working? If so, I'd be more than happy to start from scratch if it solves the issue.

Comment: you shouldn't use master branch of xsp, but the latest 3.x tag (because master branch is really unstable now, due to GSoC work)

Comment: In which case, is it safe for me to checkout another branch, build and install xsp over the existing install, or do I need to run a make uninstall on the current branch first?